# BitBucket API 2.0 - GET diff of specific file in a pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket-api

I'm attempting to automate the task of posting comments on a pull request based on static code analysis.

`https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{id}/diff` fails with a timeout for anything larger than trivial pull requests.

Is there a way of getting diff on a specific file in the pull request (I've list of files)? It is in a way more efficient because not all files will have to be commented on.

Comment: Could you do the analysis locally and then comment on BitBucket?

Comment: Analysis is happening locally. I've no issue getting full source code using `https://bitbucket.org/{owner}/{reposlug}/get/HEAD.zip` (note: I'm not cloning). My issue is while posting comments on the diff. In order to get the diff, I'm using the GET shown above which is timing out.

Comment: My suggestion was that you generate the diff using _local_ branches locally, rather than relying on BitBucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33136279/api-2.0---get-diff-of-specific-file-in-a-pull-request :

> No, it is not currently possible to narrow down a pull request diff to a subset of the files. However, I do think that that would be a useful feature and so I'll raise an internal issue to get that added.
>
> Aside from that, we should not time out on normal diffs and so I'm keen to have a closer look at some of the pull requests that are timing out for you. If you cannot share those here because they are in private repos, could you email me some at erik@atlassian.com?